# Unity: Casting between ref structs with string properties fails if done in a FixedUpdate that was not preceded by an Update

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My aim is to store snapshot data of a frame for network reconciliation purposes. The data is stored using a special collection type that only accepts unmanaged data but the unmanaged data itself can come in many forms. The classes responsible for transcribing the data to store work with a generic ref struct and the collection works with a nongeneric ref struct.

My issue is that conversions do not work correctly when they occur during a FixedUpdate that was not preceded by an Update if the ref structs being converted contain a string field (this likely extends to all reference types).

If you do the conversions via a console app there is no issue.

If you do the conversions after the first update call when your update occurs as frequently or more frequently than fixedupdate there is no issue.

If you do the conversions with ref structs that do not contain string fields there is no issue.

The issue only occurs on fixedupdates that were not preceded by an update when using KeyedRefStructs.

If you remove the FixedUpdateLoop from the PlayerLoop system and use this code while manually simulating physics there is also no issue.

Below is example code, not an actual implementation. It is intended to be the minimum amount of code needed to recreate the issue when you hit play in the unity editor.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
 
 
public readonly ref struct RefStruct
{
    public RefStruct(Span<byte> span)
    {
        Span = span;
    }
 
    public readonly Span<byte> Span;
}
```

```
public readonly ref struct RefStruct<T> where T : unmanaged
{
    public RefStruct(T state)
    {
        State = state;
    }
 
    public readonly T State;
 
    public static implicit operator T(RefStruct<T> snapshot)
    {
        return snapshot.State;
    }
 
    public static implicit operator RefStruct(RefStruct<T> snapshot)
    {
        var state = snapshot.State;
        Span<byte> span = MemoryMarshal.Cast<T, byte>(MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref state, 1));
        return new RefStruct(span);
    }
 
    public static implicit operator RefStruct<T>(RefStruct snapshot)
    {
        var span = snapshot.Span;
        T state = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, T>(span)[default];
        return new RefStruct<T>(state);
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
 
public readonly ref struct KeyedRefStruct
{
    public KeyedRefStruct((int, string) key, Span<byte> span)
    {
        Key = key;
        Span = span;
    }
 
    public readonly (int, string) Key;
    public readonly Span<byte> Span;
}
```

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
 
public readonly ref struct KeyedRefStruct<T> where T : unmanaged
{
    public KeyedRefStruct((int, string) key, T state)
    {
        Key = key;
        State = state;
    }
 
    public readonly (int, string) Key;
    public readonly T State;
 
    public static implicit operator T(KeyedRefStruct<T> snapshot)
    {
        return snapshot.State;
    }
 
    public static implicit operator KeyedRefStruct(KeyedRefStruct<T> snapshot)
    {
        var state = snapshot.State;
        Span<byte> span = MemoryMarshal.Cast<T, byte>(MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref state, 1));
        return new KeyedRefStruct(snapshot.Key, span);
    }
 
    public static implicit operator KeyedRefStruct<T>(KeyedRefStruct snapshot)
    {
        var span = snapshot.Span;
        T state = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, T>(span)[default];
        return new KeyedRefStruct<T>(snapshot.Key, state);
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class RefStructConverter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float testValue = 5f;
    public bool InspectRefSpan;
 
    int frame = default;
 
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (frame <= 2)
        {
            RefStructTest(testValue);
            KeyedRefStructTest(testValue);
        }
 
        frame++;
    }
 
    void RefStructTest(float value)
    {
        float originalValue = value;
        RefStruct<float> originalRefStruct = new RefStruct<float>(originalValue);
        RefStruct castedRefStruct = originalRefStruct;
        string inspectionResults = InspectRefSpan ? " bytes: " + ContentsToString(castedRefStruct.Span) : default;
        RefStruct<float> recastedRefStruct = castedRefStruct;
        float castedValue = recastedRefStruct;
        Debug.Log($"Frame {frame} RefStruct Expected value: {originalValue} Actual value: {castedValue} {inspectionResults}");
    }
 
    void KeyedRefStructTest(float value)
    {
        float originalValue = value;
        KeyedRefStruct<float> originalRefStruct = new KeyedRefStruct<float>(default, originalValue);
        KeyedRefStruct castedRefStruct = originalRefStruct;
        string inspectionResults = InspectRefSpan ? " bytes: " + ContentsToString(castedRefStruct.Span) : default;
        KeyedRefStruct<float> recastedRefStruct = castedRefStruct;
        float castedValue = recastedRefStruct;
        Debug.Log($"Frame {frame} KeyedRefStruct Expected value: {originalValue} Actual value: {castedValue} {inspectionResults}");
    }
 
    string ContentsToString<T>(Span<T> span)
    {
        string str = string.Empty;
 
        str += "[";
 
        for (int i = default; i < span.Length; i++)
        {
            str += $"{span[i]}";
 
            if (i < span.Length - 1)
            {
                str += $", ";
            }
            else
            {
                str += "]";
            }
        }
 
        return $"{span.Length} element(s): {str}";
    }
}
```

```
Output:
Frame 0 RefStruct Expected value: 5 Actual value: 5
Frame 0 KeyedRefStruct Expected value: 5 Actual value: 0
Frame 1 RefStruct Expected value: 5 Actual value: 5
Frame 1 KeyedRefStruct Expected value: 5 Actual value: 5
Frame 2 RefStruct Expected value: 5 Actual value: 5
Frame 2 KeyedRefStruct Expected value: 5 Actual value: 5
```

Here is a unity forum thread I made regarding the issue: https://forum.unity.com/threads/casting-ref-structs-with-string-properties-fails-if-done-in-the-first-fixedupdate-call.1454446/

A poster pointed out that the problem is likely due to the implicit cast between RefStructT and RefStruct in which a span is created over a value on the stack. This would made sense but these errors never occur for RefStructT and RefStruct, only KeyedRefStructT and KeyedRefStruct, specifically during FixedUpdates which did not have a preceding Update.

Any insight would be appreciated thank you.

I tested this code in a console app targeting the .net 2.1 standard which my unity project is also targeting and the console app worked fine as long as I ran it in release mode.

Comment: Aside from the fact that this seems like a terrible abuse AND is extremely difficult to debug, your issue actually seems to be in your implicit operator from RefStruct<T> to RefStruct. You create a span over a float and then cast it to bytes. If you look at the leading bytes, they're zero. Then, when converting back to your generic version, you index by default of T, which for float is zero, giving you the first byte in the span which is also zero. I'm not sure why you're doing this, but again, this is NOT trivial to debug.

Comment: @DavidL No the `default` there refers to `default(int)` which is the type of the `Span.Item` indexer, so in this case it's the equivalent of doing `SomeSpanOfT[0]`

Comment: @Charlieface still this only introduces confusion at best .. it will always be an `int` at that point so why not rather explicitly use `[0]` for better readability? ^^

Comment: @derHugo I don't disagree, it is weird. But it's not causing a *problem* per se

Comment: @Charlieface didn't say it is .. still something I would strongly discourage ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple: in the conversion operators, `state` is a local variable which disappears when the operator function ends. But you are using it directly to create the span.

Instead you need to use `in` parameters and `Unsafe.AsRef`

```
public static implicit operator RefStruct(in RefStruct<T> snapshot)
{
    ref var state = ref Unsafe.AsRef(in snapshot.State);
    Span<byte> span = MemoryMarshal.Cast<T, byte>(MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref state, 1));
    return new RefStruct(span);
}

public static implicit operator KeyedRefStruct(in KeyedRefStruct<T> snapshot)
{
    ref var state = ref Unsafe.AsRef(in snapshot.State);
    Span<byte> span = MemoryMarshal.Cast<T, byte>(MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref state, 1));
    return new KeyedRefStruct(snapshot.Key, span);
}
```

Note that even with this, the whole design is **highly dangerous**. The `Span<byte>` structs **must** have the same or shorter lifetime as the structs you are converting from, and therefore those `<T>` structs **must not ever**  be stored on the stack. This is exceedingly difficult to achieve, as the compiler often places values on the stack.

To be honest, you would be safer just using using these conversion functions directly on whatever values you have, which would mitigate at least some of the lifetime issues. Perhaps you could use `Memory<T>` instead, which would be far safer, although your exact use case is unclear.

**TL;DR;** You can't just use `Span<T>` willy-nilly. It is a highly restricted type, and mucking around with it using `Unsafe` can expose you to the vagaries of the unmanaged stack and GC/Jitter lifetime issues.

Comment: Check out my answer. I use a ref T in the constructor for the generic version now. I only use this so I can pair an unmanaged struct with a key and then call Frame.AddOrUpdate(snapshot); where Snapshot<T> is the ref struct outlined here. Let me know if you still see issues with it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was indeed caused by creating a span over a variable allocated on the stack.

Solution:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
 
public readonly ref struct KeyedRefStruct<T> where T : unmanaged
{
    public KeyedRefStruct((int, string) key, ref T state)
    {
        Key = key;
        Span = MemoryMarshal.Cast<T, byte>(MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref state, 1));
    }
 
    public KeyedRefStruct((int, string) key, Span<byte> span)
    {
        Key = key;
        Span = span;
    }
 
    public readonly (int, string) Key;
    public readonly Span<byte> Span;
 
    readonly T State => MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, T>(Span)[default];
 
    public static implicit operator T(KeyedRefStruct<T> snapshot) => snapshot.State;
    public static implicit operator KeyedRefStruct(KeyedRefStruct<T> snapshot) => new KeyedRefStruct(snapshot.Key, snapshot.Span);
    public static implicit operator KeyedRefStruct<T>(KeyedRefStruct snapshot) => new KeyedRefStruct<T>(snapshot.Key, snapshot.Span);
}
```

Output:

Frame 0 RefStruct Expected value: 5 Actual value: 5

Frame 0 KeyedRefStruct Expected value: 5 Actual value: 5

Frame 1 RefStruct Expected value: 5 Actual value: 5

Frame 1 KeyedRefStruct Expected value: 5 Actual value: 5

Frame 2 RefStruct Expected value: 5 Actual value: 5

Frame 2 KeyedRefStruct Expected value: 5 Actual value: 5

Comment: That's still a stack based problem. The `ref` here is going to refer to the parameter of `implicit operator` not the original storage of whereever you are calling from. It will disappear as soon as the `operator` finishes. The fact it works is just a fluke, and may stop working if you call it a different way, a different build, or sneeze twice. You need to pass the *original* `snapshot` as a `ref` or `in`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by refer to the parameter implicit operator? The original value is allocated on the stack in a function and all the spans are just pointing back to that location on the stack.

Comment: The struct is readonly, doesn't this negate the need to use an in keyword?

Comment: `implicit operator KeyedRefStruct(..` is underneath essentially a function `static KeyedRefStruct op_Implicit(KeyedRefStruct<T> snapshot)` and when you call `snapshot.Span` you get the location of the `snapshot` parameter in that function, not the location of the value you passed in to `op_Implicit`. So when you store that span in a new `KeyedRefStruct`, the lcoation it refers to will disappear when you return it back from `op_Implicit`, because the parameter is stored on the stack. `KeyedRefStruct<T>.State` is not a reference to anywhere. You can *take* a `ref` to it, but that `ref` ....

Comment: .... depends on the outer `KeyedRefStruct<T>` location, which is in this case the parameter of the `op_Implicit`. Unles you use `in` or `ref` on *that* parameter there is no way to link it back to the original location of wherever you are calling from. And even if you do link it back, that link could be further broken if you continue to pass the value around, and may even break within the same function unless you use something like `GC.KeepAlive`. No,  `readonly` is irrelevant, the parameter is simply wrong, it's a copy put on the stack when you call `op_Implicit`, and disappears when it ends

Comment: Now that I look again, I realize you have changed `KeyedRefStruct<T>` to itself contain a span. Yes, your code is fine as long as you can ensure the `ref state` you are passing in will not outlive the lifetime of the calling function. Which you might find difficult, but you haven't shown your calling code or where you use these spans.

Comment: The ref state that I pass in only exists to create a snapshot ref struct which I then add to a collection which uses a preallocated array so I don't think lifetime is an issue.

Comment: That said would I still get some benefit from using the in keyword on the implicit operators? Wouldn't modifying the original ref state still cause the same problems? My understanding is that is always something you need to keep track of when working with span.

Comment: 1. No it's not necessary, as long as you are passing a `Span` that was created from an array (or you `Cast` from such), rather than trying to create it from an internal field/parameter. 2. I'm not clear on your overall `ref` strategy so not sure exactly what you are asking.